# I have the error TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, discord.py, typeerror, last.fm

So, I am making this script that checks the most played song from a week using the Last.FM API. I have made this script in Python:

```
import discord
import datetime
from discord import member
from discord.ext import commands, tasks
from discord.utils import get
from datetime import datetime
import threading
import requests
import json
from requests.api import request

class MostPlayer(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
        self.lastfmmostplayed.start()

    @tasks.loop(seconds=1)
    async def lastfmmostplayed(self):
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        now = datetime.now()
        dt_string = now.strftime("%a %H:%M:%S")
        if(dt_string == 'Sat 17:47:00'):
            print("Time for a new song suggestion!")
            tokens = open('./hidden/tokens.json')
            tokenimport = json.load(tokens)
            lastfmtoken = tokenimport['lastfmtoken']
            # Album Chart - No. 1
            requesturl_no1album = requests.get('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getweeklyalbumchart&user=QuinnTT&api_key=' + lastfmtoken + '&format=json')
            parsed = requesturl_no1album.json()
            album = parsed['weeklyalbumchart']['album']
            sorted_album = sorted(album, key = lambda song:song["playcount"])
            most_listened_song = sorted_album[-1] # last element is the one with the biggest playcount
            album_chart_artist = most_listened_song['artist']['#text']
            album_chart_name = most_listened_song['name']
            album_chart_playcount = most_listened_song['playcount']
            album_chart_url = most_listened_song['url']
            *_, album_chart_artist_url, album_chart_name_url = album_chart_url.split("/")
            no1_info_url = ('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=album.getinfo&api_key=' + lastfmtoken + '&artist=' + album_chart_artist_url + '&album=' + album_chart_name_url + '&format=json')
            request_no_info = (requests.get(no1_info_url)).json
            album_data = json.dumps(request_no_info)
            images = album_data['album']['image']
            mega_images = [i for i in images if i['size'] == 'mega']
            try:
                mega_image_url = mega_images[0]['#text']
            except IndexError:
                mega_image_url = ""
            embed_album=discord.Embed(title="Quinn's Album of the Week:", description=f"{album_chart_name} by {album_chart_artist}", color=0x9d30ab)
            embed_album.set_footer(text=f"Quinn listened {album_chart_playcount}x to this album last week!")
            embed_album.set_image(url=mega_image_url)
            await self.bot.get_channel(850308124493086730).send(embed=embed_album)

        else:
            return

def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(MostPlayer(bot))
```

However, when I run it, I get the following error:

> TypeError: Object of type method is not JSON serializable

I have no clue what the error is, so thats why I'm asking here. Just in case it is needed, here is the JSON that is fetched from Last.FM (line 38). The code should grab the link to the image of the album so I could use that later on in the Discord.py embed.

```
{
    "album": {
        "name": "Significant Other",
        "artist": "Limp Bizkit",
        "mbid": "be3e00aa-368a-3f09-ac96-cd094e9a7151",
        "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other",
        "image": [{
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/34s/1c00f7b9cd94c2b6fbd7f12fc00bd8d2.png",
            "size": "small"
        }, {
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/64s/1c00f7b9cd94c2b6fbd7f12fc00bd8d2.png",
            "size": "medium"
        }, {
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/174s/1c00f7b9cd94c2b6fbd7f12fc00bd8d2.png",
            "size": "large"
        }, {
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/1c00f7b9cd94c2b6fbd7f12fc00bd8d2.png",
            "size": "extralarge"
        }, {
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/1c00f7b9cd94c2b6fbd7f12fc00bd8d2.png",
            "size": "mega"
        }, {
            "#text": "https://lastfm.freetls.fastly.net/i/u/300x300/1c00f7b9cd94c2b6fbd7f12fc00bd8d2.png",
            "size": ""
        }],
        "listeners": "774409",
        "playcount": "10274552",
        "tracks": {
            "track": [{
                "name": "Intro",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Intro",
                "duration": "78",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "1"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Just Like This",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Just+Like+This",
                "duration": "215",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "2"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Nookie",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Nookie",
                "duration": "289",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "3"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Break Stuff",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Break+Stuff",
                "duration": "166",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "4"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Re-Arranged",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Re-Arranged",
                "duration": "354",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "5"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "I'm Broke",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/I%27m+Broke",
                "duration": "239",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "6"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Nobody Like You",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Nobody+Like+You",
                "duration": "260",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "7"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Don't Go Off Wandering",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Don%27t+Go+Off+Wandering",
                "duration": "239",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "8"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "9 Teen 90 Nine",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/9+Teen+90+Nine",
                "duration": "276",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "9"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "N 2 Gether Now",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/N+2+Gether+Now",
                "duration": "289",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "10"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Trust?",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Trust%3F",
                "duration": "299",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "11"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "No Sex",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/No+Sex",
                "duration": "234",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "12"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Show Me What You Got",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Show+Me+What+You+Got",
                "duration": "266",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "13"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "A Lesson Learned",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/A+Lesson+Learned",
                "duration": "160",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "14"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "Outro / Radio Sucks / The Mind of Les",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/Outro+%2F+Radio+Sucks+%2F+The+Mind+of+Les",
                "duration": "438",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "15"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }, {
                "name": "[silence]",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/_/%5Bsilence%5D",
                "duration": "4",
                "@attr": {
                    "rank": "16"
                },
                "streamable": {
                    "#text": "0",
                    "fulltrack": "0"
                },
                "artist": {
                    "name": "Limp Bizkit",
                    "mbid": "8f9d6bb2-dba4-4cca-9967-cc02b9f4820c",
                    "url": "https://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit"
                }
            }]
        },
        "tags": {
            "tag": [{
                "name": "albums I own",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/albums+I+own"
            }, {
                "name": "Nu Metal",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/Nu+Metal"
            }, {
                "name": "rapcore",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/rapcore"
            }, {
                "name": "rock",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/rock"
            }, {
                "name": "limp bizkit",
                "url": "https://www.last.fm/tag/limp+bizkit"
            }]
        },
        "wiki": {
            "published": "11 Jul 2016, 20:19",
            "summary": "Significant Other is the second album by American rap rock/nu metal band Limp Bizkit. Released in 1999 by Flip/Interscope Records, the album saw the band expanding its sound from that of its debut album Three Dollar Bill, Yall, to incorporate further metal and hip hop influences. Significant Other was co-produced by Terry Date and Limp Bizkit. The album has sold at least 16 million copies worldwide. <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other\">Read more on Last.fm</a>.",
            "content": "Significant Other is the second album by American rap rock/nu metal band Limp Bizkit. Released in 1999 by Flip/Interscope Records, the album saw the band expanding its sound from that of its debut album Three Dollar Bill, Yall, to incorporate further metal and hip hop influences. Significant Other was co-produced by Terry Date and Limp Bizkit. The album has sold at least 16 million copies worldwide. <a href=\"http://www.last.fm/music/Limp+Bizkit/Significant+Other\">Read more on Last.fm</a>. User-contributed text is available under the Creative Commons By-SA License; additional terms may apply."
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the traceback of the error?

Comment: the error means you are trying to serialize method aka function, not the data. possibly you need to add () at the end of ```request_no_info = (requests.get(no1_info_url)).json```

Comment: @Biarys This seemed to work, however, I get a new error now:
TypeError: string indices must be integers